# IS the spectrum of a wav signal after filtering supposed to be similar to it before filtering-MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, filter, wav

I imported a Wav signal into matlab and I was asked to filter it and then draw the spectrum before and after filtering, The problem is that the two plots are similar the only difference is the magnitude, before filtering its very high (2500) and after filtering its only about 3.5
[image]

IS the spectrum of a wav signal after filtering supposed to be similar to it before filtering-MATLAB?

Comment: So what is the question? Edit the question or you will quickly find it closed. Put more details. Give example. Show your figures if necessary.

Comment: Ok there is an image , I filtered the signal in time domain first then got the spectrum using "fft" and plotted both signals in frequency domain, one before filtering and one after filtering

Comment: It depends what the filter is.  What is the filter?

Answer (score 0):

No! 
That's the whole point of filtering!

Magnitude change, could be an artifact of your method, or could be the actual result of your filter.

Explain what you are doing and we may be able to see what's going on.

By the way the question is more suitable for Mathematics rather than SO.